# Cascaded Parameter with multiple values selected only shows the top one

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2008, ssrs-2008

I have set up 3 cascading parameters in an SSRS report, 'Year', 'Subject' and 'Set'. All can have multiple values selected. Currently, no matter what is selected in the 3 parameters, only the 1st set is shown.

If for example, I choose years 10 & 11, for subjects Art, Biology and English and then select all the sets available (24) it will only show the set which would appear first alphabetically.

There are no filters currently set on either the parameters or groups in the report. In all the datasets the parameters are defined e.g. Subject IN (@Subject). All troubleshooting tips I have looked at seem to point to it being one of those 2.

Happy to post any information needed, just know with all the datasets, parameters, groups etc that there is a lot of information so did not want to flood the post with it.

Currently using visual studio 2008 sp1

Thanks
Rob

Comment: Are those parameters you listed in order, Year then Subject then Set? if so, is the only criteria in your dataset WHERE Subject IN (@Subject) as this would not make sense, you would normally include the lowest level in your WHERE Clause.

If this does not help, post the details of the parameters that are used in the where clause plus the actual dataset query.

Comment: Are you using stored procedures for your dataset results? If so, ensure the variables are set to be big enough to hold all the data supplied by the parameter.